# jdl file missing in new project

Tags: jhipster

When I create a jhipster thru eclipse plugin, I get src/model/Model.jdl

However this file is not available when I create the project thru online page, https://start.jhipster.tech/#/generate-application.
Did I miss can option while creating this project?

If you have the jdl for the User and Authority, kindly post the same.  I am curious to know if authority.name is an enum.  If so, how can I add few more entries to that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no JDL for User and Authority because they are not generated by the entity sub generator. I don't use Eclipse so I can't say how this Model.jdl file was created but you can easily create it from command line in your project directory by running `jhipster export-jdl src/model/Model.jdl`

Comment: jhipster export-jdl  generated an empty jdl.  May be as you said, User and Authority are not normally generated enitities.

Comment: How do I add more roles in Authority entity?  I need to add fields to the User entity and create relationship - can I do them in my new jdl file along with other entities?

Comment: For new roles into Authority, I went to the database and added new roles into JHI_AUTHORITY table.

Comment: You can't modify User in JDL, if you need to it's only by modifying generated code.Please accept my answer if it solved your initial question  and open new questions if you need. New roles can also be added into `src/main/resources/config/liquibase/authorithies.csv`